# How do you install new level packs in Lego Dimensions?

Tags: lego-dimensions

How do I install new level packs in Lego Dimensions?

I just bought the Back to the Future pack and I've built the hoverboard and the DeLorean but I can't work out how to unlock the level.

The title screen tells me there is an update but how do I install it?

I'm on the PS3 version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You know when you search for an answer to a problem you've been having and you can't find anything and it ends up being something stupid?

This is one of those times.

My ethernet cable was unplugged and when I plugged it in the game ended up needing an update which it prompted me for when I restarted the game.

The content was then unlocked.